# How would I add a csv file into my python code?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a python code and I am learning to use csv files. How would i open a csv file with information on it and, for example use my csv to print information.
An example of this would be I could put print 1A and it would print the information in 1A on the csv file.
Thank you for your help any code would be very helpful however any tips are welcome too thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Python has a module built-in for handling csv's! It is called, unsurprisingly, "csv," and you can find the [official documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html).

To answer your question about printing a particular cell, the reader function of this module will return an iterator that gives you each row of the csv as a list of strings.

Simply `import csv` and away you go! Good luck!